# Getting a file using curl or wget from command line doesn't work (in php it's working ....)

Tags: curl, wget

I'm on Ubuntu 15 ....

I need to download this open data CSV http://www.sviluppoeconomico.gov.it/images/exportCSV/prezzo_alle_8.csv

from this page

http://www.sviluppoeconomico.gov.it/index.php/it/open-data/elenco-dataset/2032336-carburanti-prezzi-praticati-e-anagrafica-degli-impianti.

I'd like to use a simply wget or curl command line but if I try for example

```
curl http://www.sviluppoeconomico.gov.it/images/exportCSV/prezzo_alle_8.csv pippo.csv
```

the result is

```
<html><head><title>Richiesta Rifiutata</title></head><body>La URL Richiesta e' stata riufiuta. Contattare l'amministratore di sistema.<br><br>The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.<br><br></body></html>    
<html>
 <head><title>302 Found</title></head>
  <body bgcolor="white">
   <center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
   <hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
  </body>
</html>
```

the same result if I use

```
wget http://www.sviluppoeconomico.gov.it/images/exportCSV/prezzo_alle_8.csv
```

I've tried to use a simply php progam

```
<?php
 $url = 'http://www.sviluppoeconomico.gov.it/images/exportCSV/prezzo_alle_8.csv';

 print $url;
 echo '<br>';
 echo '<br>';

 //#Set CURL parameters: pay attention to the PROXY config !!!!
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 echo $data;
?>
```

and in this case the data of the CSV file is printed on my browser page (i've to wait for it but it's printed ....).

So, I think that should be possible to download the data using curl or wget from command line and probably there are some parameters that I should set but I don't have the solution now ...

Any suggestions / examples?

Thank you in advance!!

Cesare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `-L` switch with your `curl` command as you are using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);` from your php code to follow the redirection.

More information about this `-L` switch can be found here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L

Also override the default curl user agent string (i.e. `User-Agent: curl/7.40.0`) with following option

```
 -A "Opera"
```

For `wget` command add the following switch for useragent string.

```
-U "Opera"
```

Comment: I've tried it but it does't work for me .... Did you try it and is it working for you? Thanks!!!

Comment: I didn't try. The curl commandline by default add user agent string something like `curl/x.x.x` and possibly which denies by the server. So override that using `-A "Opera"` and it should be fine with you!

Comment: Ok, It's working now .... the command is .......  curl -L -A "Opera" http://www.sviluppoeconomico.gov.it/images/exportCSV/prezzo_alle_8.csv > pippo.csv

Comment: @Sabui Hassan do you have also the solution using wget command line?

Comment: Yes. For `wget` you need to add `-U "Opera"` with your command.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I've tried this.... wget -U "Opera" http://www.sviluppoeconomico.gov.it/images/exportCSV/prezzo_alle_8.csv ...... and all works fine.